# Read Json and update template from mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I have a Index.html file, where I am using container class. 
I have another html file with which contains mustache variables.

Here is the code which I am using,

Lets say this is a.html.

```
<script id="filtersOptions" type="text/html">
    <ul class="checkboxCommonContent">
    {{#data}}
    <li>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox"><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label><span class="lblText">{{brand_name}}</span>
    </div>
    </li>
    {{/data}}

    </ul>
```

I have a json file, where the brand information something like this,

```
{
    "brands":[
        {
            "brand_name":"Adidas",
            "available_products":30
        }

    ]
}
```

Through Javascript I am featching the Json data and trying to udapete the mustache tempalte but getting error. 
Featchng information from js

```
loadFileForFilters: function(){


    $.getJSON('js/json/brand.json', {}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHr) {
              console.log(data);
              var f = $("#filtersOptions").html();
              $.get('files/sort_and_filter_lb.html', function(template, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                  var template = Mustache.render(f, {data: data});
                  //$(".container").html(template);

              });
          });
          }
```

container - Is in side index.html.
The sort_and_filter_lb.html file have following code

```
<script id="filtersOptions" type="text/html"><ul class="checkboxCommonContent"> {{#data}} <li> <div> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox"><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label><span class="lblText">{{brand_name}}</span> </div> </li> {{/data}} </ul> </script>
```

Can some one please guide me. Why I am not getting the data in the main template.

Comment: What is expected response from `$.get()` ? Is `template` (response from `$.get()`) being overwritten by `var template = Mustache.render(f, {data: data});` ?

Comment: expected response is to render the template then pass the data to update it.

Comment: Basically I am trying to load Mustache.js templates from an external file with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Edit,

Browsed some documentations [MUSTACHE MANUAL](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) , and demonstrations [A Simple Mustache Demo](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/easy-html-templates-with-mustache/demo.html) , along with re-reading Question , for introduction into `Mustache.js` .

At first glance ,  appear that `json` object at `brand.json` does not have `data` property to correspond to `{{#data}}` ; see http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Sections at `template` and `hash` of `{{#repo}}`.

Not certain about necessity of second ajax call, i.e., `$.get()` ? Existing `#filtersOptions` (`f`) html could be modified , to reduce ajax call to first , `$.getJSON()` ?

Above portions not directly addressed here , though ajax pieces re-arranged to process their respective return values within `.then()` callback .

Changed `<script>` element at `sort_and_filter_lb.html` file to `<div>` , for jsfiddle to process .

Note, Not previously tried `Mustache.js`

Try

v2

html

```
<script id="filtersOptions" type="text/html">
    <ul class="checkboxCommonContent"> {{#data}}
    <li> <div> <input type="checkbox"
    id="checkbox-1-1"
    class="regular-checkbox" /> <label
    for="checkbox-1-1"> </label><span class="lblText">{{brand_name}}</span> </div>
    </li> {{/data}}

    </ul>
</script>
<div class="process">
    <button>Process Template</button>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

js

```
$(function () {

    $(".process button").on("click", function () {

        var f = $('#filtersOptions').html();

        var _data = {
            "brands": {
                "data": [{
                    "brand_name": "Adidas"
                }, {
                    "available_products": 30
                }]
            }
        };

        var file = String('<div id=filtersOptions type=text/html>'
                          +'<ul class=checkboxCommonContent> {{#data}} <li>' 
                          +'<div>' 
                          +'<input type=checkbox id=checkbox-1-1 class=regular-checkbox>'
                          +'<label for=checkbox-1-1></label>'
                          +'<span class=lblText>{{brand_name}}</span>'
                          +'</div> </li> {{/data}} </ul> </div>');

        var request1 = $.post("/echo/json/", {
            json: JSON.stringify(_data)
        }, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            return data.brands;
        });

        var request2 = $.post("/echo/html/", {
            html: file
        }, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            return data
        });
        $.when(request1, request2)
            .then(function (a, b) {
            console.log(a[0], b[0]);
            var html = Mustache.render(b[0] /* or , `f` */, a[0].brands);
            $('#container').html(html);
        })
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/uhf73/

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears a little messed up but close. If you want to render a template using an external file and external data, try something like this:

```
$.getJSON('js/json/brand.json', {}, function(data) {
     // on success, request template
     $.get('files/sort_and_filter_lb.html', function(template_string) {
         // when we have both template and data, render it
         var output = Mustache.render(template_string, {data: data});
         $(".container").html(output);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Even I tried using this one also but no luck https://github.com/jonnyreeves/jquery-Mustache

Comment: Is `template_string` and `data` what you expect when you `console.log` them? `template_string` should be the mustache template. What's the content of `output`? This should work.

Comment: I tried this but data is not being updated in template_string. :(

Comment: template_string should be your mustache template. What's in it?

Comment: My template string is somthing like this <script id="filtersOptions" type="text/html"><ul class="checkboxCommonContent">
{{#data}}
<li>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox"><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label><span class="lblText">{{brand_name}}</span>
</div>
</li>
{{/data}}

</ul>
</script>